# Get data from 3 tables (laravel eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have 3 tables namely:
`hotels`, `hotel_rooms` and `hotel_room_images`

```
hotels:
id  | name             | desc
1   | my hotel name    | sth

hotel_rooms:
id | hotel_id | room_name 
1  |    1     | my 1st room
2  |    1     | my 2nd room

hotel_room_images:
id | hotel_id | room_id | image  
1  |    1     |    1    | my image
2  |    1     |    1    | my next image
1  |    1     |    2    | my image
2  |    1     |    2    | my next image
```

I have defined my relationships as below:

`Hotel.php` Model

```
public function room()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\HotelRoom', 'hotel_id');
}
```

`HotelRoom.php` Model

```
public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\HotelRoomImage', 'room_id');
 }
```

I am able to get all hotels with rooms from this eloquent query in `Hotel.php` Model:

```
public function getHotelByToken($token)
{
   return $this->with('room')
                ->where('token', $token)
                ->first();
    }
```

**My Question**: I want to get every room details and their respective room images. How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: What's the problem actually if you have defined relationship correctly then you can easily get the details you need

Comment: i am unable to define any relationship from `hotel.php` model that link to `hotelRoomImage.php` model.

Comment: have a look at this in docs you will get idea https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I am able to get room images but I have to access it as `$hotel->roomImages` and `$hotel->room` differently, I want to get room images  inside room attribute so that I can access it as `$hotel->room->roomImages`

Comment: You're using a `hasMany` for `room` so it's always going to return a collection not a single instance. I'm assuming the that hotel has more than one room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all rooms with images with:

```
return $this->with('room.images')
            ->where('token', $token)
            ->first();
```

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Great! works perfect. This was easier to solve than I really thought :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
public function rooms()
{
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\HotelRoom', 'hotel_id');
}



$hotel = Hotel::with('rooms.images')->find(1);

foreach($hotel->rooms as $room)

         foreach($room->images as $image)
               // you have single image here
         endforeach
endforeach
```